# Tensorflow stops training and hanged on GPU randomly

Tags: tensorflow, slurm

When I run the following code on GPU, it trains well for some epoches and then just hangs.
While hanged processes are still alive but the GPU usages become 0%.
In the below code I am using Dataset API from tf.contrib.data.Dataset. But I also tried using placeholder and feed dictionary approach which hangs as well on random epoch during training. 
I am struggling with the problem for last 2-3 weeks and cannot find a way out.
I am running the code on a remote GPU cluster. Here are some information about cluster node,
Using tensorflow gpu version 1.4

> NodeName=node050 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=1    CPUAlloc=0
>   CPUErr=0 CPUTot=24 CPULoad=12.03 Features=Proc24,GPU4    Gres=gpu:4
>   NodeAddr=node050 NodeHostName=node050 Version=15.08    OS=Linux
>   RealMemory=129088 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=125664 Sockets=24 Boards=1
>   State=IDLE ThreadsPerCore=1 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A
>   BootTime=2017-11-07T08:20:00 SlurmdStartTime=2017-11-07T08:24:06
>   CapWatts=n/a    CurrentWatts=0 LowestJoules=0 ConsumedJoules=0
>   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s

CODE

```
dat_split = np.load('data/dat_split2.npy')
X_train = dat_split[0].astype(np.float32)
X_test = dat_split[1].astype(np.float32)
y_train = dat_split[2].astype(np.int32)
y_test = dat_split[3].astype(np.int32)

num_epochs = 100


train_data_len = X_train.shape[0]
test_data_len = X_test.shape[0]
num_joints = len(considered_joints)
num_classes = len(classes)


############ taking batch_size even data##########
even_train_len = (train_data_len//batch_size)*batch_size
even_test_len = (test_data_len//batch_size)*batch_size

X_train = X_train[:even_train_len]
X_test = X_test[:even_test_len]
y_train = y_train[:even_train_len]
y_test = y_test[:even_test_len]


train_dat = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
train_dat = train_dat.batch(batch_size)

test_dat  = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))
test_dat = test_dat.batch(batch_size)

iterator = Iterator.from_structure(train_dat.output_types, train_dat.output_shapes)

trainig_iterator_init = iterator.make_initializer(train_dat)
test_iterator_init = iterator.make_initializer(test_dat)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    global_cell = GlobalLSTM(num_units=num_units_each_cell, num_joints=num_joints)   #GlobalLSTM is a subtype of RNNCell
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
    X_loaded2, Y_loaded = next_element
    X_loaded = tf.where(tf.is_nan(X_loaded2), tf.zeros_like(X_loaded2), X_loaded2)

    init_state = global_cell.zero_state((batch_size), tf.float32)
    rnn_ops, rnn_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(global_cell, X_loaded, dtype=tf.float32)

    with tf.variable_scope('softmax__'):
        W = tf.get_variable('W', [(num_joints)*num_units_each_cell, num_classes], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.0, 1.0))
        b = tf.get_variable('b', [num_classes], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.0, 1.0))



    final_logits = tf.matmul(rnn_state[1], W) + b       # taking h state of rnn 
    with tf.name_scope("loss_comp"):
        total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=final_logits, labels=tf.one_hot(Y_loaded, num_classes)))
    with tf.name_scope("train_step"):
        train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(total_loss)

    with tf.name_scope("pred_accu"):
        predictions = tf.nn.softmax(final_logits)
        pred2 = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), [-1, 1])
        correct_pred = tf.equal(pred2, tf.cast(Y_loaded, tf.int64))
        accuracy_ = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))



    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        tic = time.clock()    
        for step in range(num_epochs):
            sess.run(trainig_iterator_init)
            batch_cnt = train_data_len//batch_size
            epch_loss = 0.0
            epch_acc = 0.0
            for bt in range(batch_cnt):
                _, loss_, acc = sess.run([train_step, total_loss, accuracy_])
                epch_loss += loss_
                epch_acc += acc
            print ('loss after epoch, ', step,': ', epch_loss/batch_cnt, ' ## accuracy : ', epch_acc/batch_cnt)

        print ("optimization finished, time required: ", time.clock()-tic)


        #############test accuracy##############
        batch_cnt = test_data_len//batch_size
        sess.run(test_iterator_init)
        print ('testing accuracy on test data : batch number', batch_cnt)
        epch_acc = 0.0
        for bt in range(batch_cnt):
            acc = sess.run(accuracy_)
            epch_acc += acc
        print ('testing accuracy : ', epch_acc/batch_cnt)
```

Here are some screen shot of different hangs,
**Hanged on an epoch**
[image: hanged_epc]
**GPU usage that time**
[image: hanged]
**GPU usage while running (not hanged)**
[image: running_gpuusage]
**Hanged on another eopch**
[image: hanged2]

This type of random hanging behavior keeps repeating on each run. 
Each time it hangs on a random epoch. That's why I cannot figure out what is going wrong.
By looking at code or other set up can anybody please give me any idea about what is going wrong or how can I debug this out? Thanks

Comment: Well, one way to start debugging would be to extract a stack trace from TensorFlow while it's hung (e.g. run Python in gdb and send it SIGINT when it's stuck). Can you reproduce on a single GPU?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. One CPU core had a workload of 100% while the GPU was hanging. I thought this was an issue of the lock and checked the code of tensorflow [gpu_event_mgr.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5fbda9d8da7b98f62e83a392f047adf307b48b02/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.cc#L133).
"queue_empty" wasn't protected by mutex_lock, so the CPU would hang and couldn't send data to the GPU.

My temporary solution is setting the parameter

`gpu_options.polling_inactive_delay_msecs = 10 (default value is 1)`

or to a bigger number in the session's ConfigProto. This will make the CPU wait longer when the queue was empty and fill more data, which will be sent to the GPU. It will prevent the dead lock. This solution just reduces the probability of a hanging GPU and it isn't a final solution. However, it allowed my deep neural network training to finished most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Also this is true in my case that, if I suspend the process using "kill -stop p_id" then resume it using "kill -cont p_id", the training starts from exactly where it stopped. I wrote another script which does this in 60 seconds interval so that training can continue.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved a similar issue as follows:

I ran my code on a virtual device with GTX 1080 Ti GPU, Python 3.7 and the latest version of the tensorflow-gpu 2.1. I had the same issue for a week. None of the solutions and workarounds seemed to work for me.

I downgraded my **tensorflow-gpu**. I also had to downgrade my Python since tensorflow-gpu 1.* versions do not work on Python 3.7.

- **Python** from 3.7 to **3.6**
- **Tensorflow-gpu** from 2.1 to **1.12**

Of course, I had to change some parts of my code to be compatible with the older version of tensorflow-gpu but it got rid of the GPU hung issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is always necessary to have same amount or higher of RAM memory to CUDA memory.

1. Try checking out num_workers

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Halo9Pan was great and set me on the right course. I added the code

```
configproto = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto() 
configproto.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
configproto.gpu_options.polling_inactive_delay_msecs = 10
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=configproto) 
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

to the beginning of my network as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452289/why-is-my-gpu-getting-interrupted-when-training-my-data). That solved the issue for me.