# Why is my GPU getting interrupted when training my data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I spent hours configuring my computer and finally got to make python train data on GPUs instead of CPU. However, for some reason my models keep getting interrupted halfway during the middle of their epochs and I cannot complete the training of the models.

Waiting for the computer does not solve this problem and I cannot interrupt the kernel either. I tried other people's solution and still don't have much luck.

I can train my model normally if I'm using a CPU (at a crawling rate), but when I switch to GPU my model trains really fast before they hang up half way, not completing all the epochs that are required. My python kernel also gets stuck on running after that and I cannot interrupt it unless I terminate the whole thing from task manager.

From my task manager performance history, during training there is a sustained spike at my GPU, which is expected. But when it hangs up my GPU activity goes back to 0, even though my kernel indicates that the training is still in the middle of its epoch. This happens randomly and is not dependent on the timing or the number of epochs, although it is more likely to happen the longer I train the data.

Here is my sequential model.

```
def prepare_sequences(notes, n_vocab, seq_len):
    """ Prepare the sequences used by the Neural Network """
    sequence_length = seq_len

    names = sorted(set(item for item in notes))
    note_to_int = dict((note, number) for number, note in enumerate(names))

    network_input = []
    network_output = []

    # create input sequences and the corresponding outputs
    for i in range(0, len(notes) - sequence_length, 1):
        sequence_in = notes[i:i + sequence_length]
        sequence_out = notes[i + sequence_length]
        network_input.append([note_to_int[char] for char in sequence_in])
        network_output.append(note_to_int[sequence_out])

    n_patterns = len(network_input)

    # reshape the input into a format compatible with LSTM layers
    network_input = numpy.reshape(network_input, (n_patterns, sequence_length, 1))
    # normalize input
    network_input = network_input / float(n_vocab)

    network_output = np_utils.to_categorical(network_output)

    return (network_input, network_output)

def create_network(network_input, n_vocab, LSTM_node_count, Dropout_count):
    """ create the structure of the neural network """
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(
        LSTM_node_count,
        input_shape=(network_input.shape[1], network_input.shape[2]),
        recurrent_dropout= Dropout_count,
        return_sequences=True
    ))
    model.add(LSTM(
        LSTM_node_count, 
        return_sequences=True, 
        recurrent_dropout= Dropout_count,))
    model.add(LSTM(LSTM_node_count))
    model.add(BatchNorm())
    model.add(Dropout(Dropout_count))
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNorm())
    model.add(Dropout(Dropout_count))
    model.add(Dense(n_vocab))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

    return model

def train(model, network_input, network_output, epoch, batchsize):
    """ train the neural network """
    filepath = "trained_weights/" + "weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}-bigger.hdf5"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath,
        monitor='loss',
        verbose=0,
        save_best_only= True,
        mode='min'
    )
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

    model.fit(network_input, 
              network_output, 
              epochs= epoch,
              batch_size= batchsize, 
              callbacks= callbacks_list)
```

```
configproto = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto() 
configproto.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
configproto.gpu_options.polling_inactive_delay_msecs = 10
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=configproto) 
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

During training, I also get a warning message and I don't know what it means.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_1 will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
```

```
C:\Users\David>nvidia-smi
Sun Dec 27 15:56:16 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.89       Driver Version: 460.89       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050   WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    120MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      5496    C+G   ...5n1h2txyewy\SearchApp.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7372    C+G   ...nputApp\TextInputHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8268    C+G   ...wekyb3d8bbwe\Music.UI.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9420    C+G   ...artMenuExperienceHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10084    C+G   ...ekyb3d8bbwe\YourPhone.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11292    C+G   Insufficient Permissions        N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14684    C+G   ...cw5n1h2txyewy\LockApp.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am currently using tensorflow 2.4, CUDA 11.2,

Comment: What is the activation function of your LSTM cell/layer?

Comment: What does "my models keep getting interrupted" mean? Please provide evidence of this.

Comment: Activation= 'relu'. Models getting interrupted refer to it being stuck in the middle of the epoch. The problem seems to be similar to the descriptions of this thread  https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8595

Comment: Please provide full details, model, code, etc, the more details the better.

Comment: I've updated my question with sequential model and description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `recurrent_dropout > 0` which does not meet the LSTM compatibility  [requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn#performance_optimization_and_cudnn_kernels) to ensure CuDNN optimizations. Make `recurrent_dropout = 0` to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I changed recurrent_dropout = 0 and the issue is fixed. I have no idea why does that happen, but it solves the problem.